# WinJS Databind to property get/set

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

In WinJS can I bind a property getter in a listView? Say I have an object defined like this:

```
var MyLib = MyLib || {};

MyLib.ToDoItem = function() {
  this.name = '';
  this.description = '';
  Object.defineProperty(this, "completed", {
    get : function() {
      return false;
    }
  });
}

MyLib.ToDoList = []; 
//MyLib.ToDoList.push....add todo items
```

I am declaring a WinJS.Binding.Template where all of the properties are binding except the one that is defined with a property getter:

```
<div id="myItemTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
  <div class="titleTile">
    <h4 class="item-title" data-win-bind="textContent: name"></h4>

    <p data-win-bind="textContent: description"></p>

    <div data-win-bind="textContent: completed"></div> <-- Renders as undefined
    </div>
</div>
```

The "completed" property renders as undefined. If I put a breakpoint in the javascript console where I am loading the data, I can get to the completed property, but the databinding doesn't seem to like it...any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed one line after your getter.

```
get : function() {
  return false;
}
, enumerable: true
```

By setting enumerable to true, you can make data binding works on this property.

Comment: By the way, you should move function and property definitions outside your constructor, you'll get better performance by doing this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781219.aspx#structure_objects_correctly

Comment: thanks I will give it a try tonight!. Regarding moving property getter/setter to prototype, not sure how I can do that since I have backing variables (not shown in example). e.g. my get is "return _completed;"

Comment: Put the backing variables in the object (this.something) not in the closure in your constructor. You sacrifice some theoretical object privacy, but will gain in performance.

Comment: @ChrisTavares doesn't that kind of defeat the purpose? Not too concerned about performance at the moment, but will keep that in mind. Related note, this looked interesting http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553524.aspx

Comment: In my opinion, in JavaScript that kind of object privacy is overrated and causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: @minamo just curious, how did you know enumerable would make it bindable? Is there documentation for this?

Comment: @BZ I didn't know what exactly would make it bindable. But I guessed WinJS must used some ways to iterate/enumerate throughout your object, by Object.keys or for..in. Therefore you should set enumerable to true to expose that property.

Comment: Just to add up, enumerable is a keyword not just for WinJS.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty